# Using multiple casting types in single function (c overloading workarounds)

Tags: c, types, casting, overloading, dry

C programmer trying to get over Python here.
I find myself repeatedly breaking the DNY rule, and I want to know if there's a way to pass an unknown type into a function and act upon it and change its type dynamically. Currently, I have:

```
static void ArrayFunction( void *one, void *two, uint8_t size )
{
   // Get the array lengths.
   if ( size == sizeof( uint8_t ) )
   {
      uint8_t *One = one;
      uint8_t *Two = two;
   }
   if ( size == sizeof( uint16_t ) )
   {
      uint16_t *One = one;
      uint16_t *Two = two;
   }
   if ( size == sizeof( uint32_t ) )
   {
      uint32_t *One = one;
      uint32_t *Two = two;
   }

   for ( i = 0; i < MAX_BUSES; i++ )
   {
      // Do something with the arrays.
      One[i] = Two[i];

      // Lots more code here. Maybe hundreds of lines. 
   }
}
```

As you know, this code does not compile because the two variables defined immediately fall out of scope. I want to pass in an array of 8, 16, 32, etc. length and do something with it no matter what. I know that I can't just use the void pointer because the array length differs when different integer types are used. If I copy the for loop into each of the if statements, I have three copies of the exact same code. Is this too complicated of a thing to do in C, or is there a workaround that reduces the number of times I have to copy and paste? Thanks!

Comment: Could you please formulate the essence of what you want to know in one question?

Comment: Sorry, just reworked it with a more generic example. It's been a while since I had to ask a question of my own here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case that you are presenting now, a simple `memcpy` with the appropriate size for the whole array would do.

If you really want to do more complicated things without code repetition, you could encapsulate your code by a macro, and just repeat the calls inside the `if`s.

There is not much more you can do, C is not dynamically typed.

BTW, in C instead of several `if`s you would typically use a `switch`.

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling that it wasn't possible, but I wanted to at lest ask. I knew about macros, but I don't think that it would improve code readability enough to be worth it.